# get lowest value from checkbox

Tags: php, forms

The checkbox provides the altitude of a skiresort. After 'posting' (by ajax) the form I would like to get the lowest value. What is the way to do this?

At the receiving end I need to catch the value  (as an integer):

```
       <?php
            //post

$altitudes = isset($_REQUEST['altitude']) ? $_REQUEST['altitude'] : array();
sort($altitudes, SORT_NUMERIC);


 foreach($altitudes as $value) {
  if $value > 0; $hohe = $value; break;
}

        ?>

<div class="list-group">
    <h3>Altitude</h3>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">
        <input class="item_filter altitude"  name="altitude[]" value="500" type="checkbox"> &nbsp;&nbsp; 500
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">
        <input class="item_filter altitude"  name="altitude[]" value="1200" type="checkbox"> &nbsp;&nbsp; 1200
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">
        <input class="item_filter altitude"  name="altitude[]" value="1400" type="checkbox"> &nbsp;&nbsp; 1400
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">
        <input class="item_filter altitude"  name="altitude[]" value="1800" type="checkbox"> &nbsp;&nbsp; 1800
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">
        <input class="item_filter altitude"  name="altitude[]" value="2200" type="checkbox"> &nbsp;&nbsp; 2200
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">
        <input class="item_filter altitude"  name="altitude[]" value="2600" type="checkbox"> &nbsp;&nbsp; 2600
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">
        <input class="item_filter altitude"  name="altitude[]" value="3000" type="checkbox"> &nbsp;&nbsp; 3000
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have any input name?

Comment: no, put i can add something like this name="altitude[]"

Comment: If you want to do this via php you need those inputs to be in a form that submits the data to `yourprocessingpage.php` and have a name so they can be serialized.
That done, update your code and set us see what you did in `yourprocessingpage.php` so far. Here is little guide about that: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Loop through the results in your controller and identify the one that has the lowest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your altitudes array, grab the first value and assign it as `$min_val` then check each subsequent value.  If the next value is less than the `$min_val`, reassign `$min_val` as that value.

```
$altitudes = isset($_POST['altitude']) ? $_POST['altitude'] : array();

if(!empty($altitudes)){
    foreach($altitudes as $value) {
        if(!isset($min_val) || $value < $min_val){
            $min_val = $value;
        } 
    }       
}
```

`$min_val` will be your lowest value

Comment: thanks Dan. I realized that I receive the altitude by ajax. Somehow this does not work: $altitudes = isset($_REQUEST['altitude']) ? $_REQUEST['altitude'] : array();

Comment: the looping logic should work here as long as you have the array of altitudes.  I'm not sure where that data is but if you hardcoded an array like $altitudes = array(500,700,1000,300,200,3400); and run it through this loop it will give you the desired result.